# Understanding Standard Deviation of means when sampling 100% of the population multiple times

Tags: r, sample, mean, standard-deviation, replicate

This may sound like an incredibly naive question but here's what I'm doing and here's why this has had me stumped.

I have a population of 1000 samples from which I am trying to sub-sample 5%, 10%, 15%...... 100% using the following code in R.

```
subData <- replicate(30, sample(Data,55,replace=TRUE))
```

I am then computing the mean and Standard deviation for further analysis. What is confusing me is when I am selecting 100% of the population and replicating it 30 times, with replace=TRUE, why is the Standard Deviation of means non-zero? Surely, if one selects all the data points 100 times and calculates the mean it should be the same and hence Standard deviation should be 0. Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong with my code in R?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you say will be true if you set `replace=FALSE`. Setting `replace=TRUE` you allow single elements to be drawn several times and so you may have different means.

Comment: Congratulations, you've discovered [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)).

Comment: Thanks @Roland and Nicola. I did accidentally discover bootstrapping!